# App Engine localhost publication from eclipse-photon

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I had been working on Google app engine for some time with great success. However, recently I was forced to upgrade to Eclipse-Photon from Eclipse-Mars.

I can run a debugging version of the server on localhost:8080 just fine except when I change any of the TypeScript files. Formerly when I would run the TypeScript compiler to generate new JavaScript the server would automatically update the server. Now when I generate a new JavaScript file, the server continues to serve the old version. I have my expirations set to 0 and I have automatic publication turned on.

For a while I could make it work by telling the server to Publish. Now that has stopped working as well. If I save any file from inside of Eclipse I see a little message flash by indicating publication and then that file serves properly. If I load the generated JavaScript file and then modify it slightly then it will publish and serve correctly.

Obviously Photon is no longer tracking file changes that way that Mars did. I could easily copy the generated file to the correct place if I knew where that place was.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your TypeScript compilation from outside of Eclipse?  If so, try doing a *Refresh* of your project.  That should sync up Eclipse's notion of the filesystem state with what is on disk.

Cloud Tools for Eclipse relies on the *Web Tools* and  *Resources* frameworks to determine whether a resource has changed and needs publishing.  Eclipse is normally set up to detect resource changes automatically as configured by two options on the *Preferences > General > Workspace* preference page: *Refresh on access* and *Refresh using native hooks or polling*.

Comment: Perfect. The Refresh on access was set but Refresh using native hooks or polling was not. Setting that cured the problem.